# Changing default log size in git

Tags: git

I want when I write `git log` to just show, say, 20 commits.

I know this can be done by writing `git log -20`.

But want to make it default.

Comment: Create an alias like `git.l.20`

Comment: Yea, so far as I can tell there's no configuration property for the log size. An alias might be a good bet, you could make it shorter like `gl` (`git-log`) if you don't want to type so much.

Answer (score 2):

While there is no configuration setting to limit the number of commits listed by `git-log`, you can always make an [alias](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases):

```
git config alias.lg "log -20"
```

Or, if you want to make it available to *all* repositories on the local machine:

```
git config --global alias.lg "log -20"
```

At this point, you can simply say:

```
git lg
```

And you'll get a list of 20 commits.

Comment: What I wanted most was to know a variable name to fix in config, and not do it with aliases. But maybe there is no such variable and this is the best possible.